# How can I create a HTML button that opens a link in a .php table?

Tags: php, html, button, hyperlink, html-table

First of all, I have very little programming experience and even less with .php

I'm actually trying to figure out the code that our last programmer left us before he quit his job.

Basically, I have a table with information inside.

The multiple information is useful to create a new string that is a hyperlink.

My variable is the "build-up hyperlink string" called `$createdlink`.

It's all working well but the links are looking like this :

```
http://www.fdksmsdkldfkmkdfmhd.com/search/?kldsmnfkjldsfgsdfjgnfsdjkgfjdknkmgfdlkmfgkfdmglkfdmlgfdkl
```

It's taking too much place in the table.

My goal is to create HTML buttons inside my table so it's taking less space and it's doing the same job.

Here is what my "working code" looks like

```
echo '<td class="'.$info->type.'">'.$createdlink.'&nbsp;</td>';
```

How can I insert a HTML button replacing the `$createdlink` ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) - as for how to style it as a button, you have several options, but the simplest way to get a smaller link would look something like `"<a href='$createdlink'>Go</a>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$form = "<form action='$createdlink'>";
$form .= "<input type='submit' value='This is a button link'>";
$form .= "</form>";
echo '<td class="'.$info->type.'">'.$form.'&nbsp;</td>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!

That’s almost it. 

There is only one thing… The button is working, but it’s going to the link that is not fully created

Here is my “created link”

    $createdlink = 'http://www.website.com/search/?q='.rawurlencode($info->info1).'%20'.rawurlencode($info->info2).'restofthewebsite.html' ;

When I click the button, it goes directly to http://www.website.com/search/?q=  without the other strings.

Is it because of the apostrophes that are not at the right place? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try removing apostrophes from `<form action='$createdlink'>` like
`<form action=$createdlink>`

Comment: I understand what I'm doing wrong. I need to figure out the special characters because there is a "?" in my search string. As soon as I find out how, it will be perfect. Thanks alot Allkin!

Comment: Try to encode the link again with
`$createdlink = urlencode($createdlink);`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried but it does not work. The website doesn't accept the '?' conversion as a '%3F' in the link. I really feel like I'm close to the goal...